# symfony/encore: Hide warning of dependency

Tags: webpack-encore

I am struggling to hide a warning that comes from a dependency I can not fix.

Things I've tried:

- configuring the webpack config `stats` option; but I saw later that Encore essentially disables the warnings output already (when looking at the output of `Encore.getWebpackConfig()`).
- writing a transformer for the `friendly-errors-plugin` used by encore; settings the warning I do not want to see to `null`. After transformations however the `null` values are not filtreed out, leading to a crash (kind of makes sense, as they are not filters; but was worth a shot)

What confuses me that apparently the `friendly-errors-webpack-plugin` takes its input from the webpack output [see source](https://github.com/geowarin/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/blob/master/src/core/extractWebpackError.js), but the warnings still show up even if I disable all with `stats: false`.

In short; how can I hide this warning:

```
 WARNING  Compiled with 1 warnings                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     8:44:25 AM

 warning  in ./node_modules/moment/locale/en-SG.js

There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* /home/famoser/Repos/mangelio/web/node_modules/moment/locale/en-SG.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    /home/famoser/Repos/mangelio/web/node_modules/moment/locale sync /^\.\/.*$/
* /home/famoser/Repos/mangelio/web/node_modules/moment/locale/en-sg.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    /home/famoser/Repos/mangelio/web/node_modules/moment/locale sync /^\.\/.*$/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, remove folder node_modules and yarn/npm install resolves the issue, thanks!